# Tips for using the Lensbaby 3G?

Tags: lens, technique, tips, tilt-shift, lensbaby

I just picked one up as a much less expensive option than a tilt/shift lens for the Pentax mount (they're hard to find and crazy expensive for the K-mount). I have done some experimental shots with it, discovering that I clearly need practice, but beyond that, does anyone have experience with these and have some tips to share?

Comment: John, I'm curious: do _you_ have any tips a year later?

Comment: @mattdm - To be honest, I haven't used it all that much. It's a lens that requires some planning because it takes some work to put it to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't use a lensbaby and don't have any great resources for you, but seeing that the question has gone unanswered for so long, I'll post what I can...

Craig of The Mindful Eye uses a Lensbaby.  Back in the day he posted more how-to stuff about using it, but there are some of his photos along with nuggets of info in his blog:
http://www.craigtannercreative.com/lightdiary/?cat=18
...he also seems to be good at answering questions, so maybe you can ask him directly?  Or search his site and see if you can find more useful information -I stopped following him after he changed from his old site to this new one, so it's possible that I missed some better resources there.

Comment: Indeed, really great work there. The Lensbaby really adds a whole new level to photography...

Comment: Link is dead by now :/